# How to access the WebHooks POST data in Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-ci

I have successfully set up a local environment with Jenkins and Gitlab running locally. I have created a WebHook, which sends a POST to Jenkins whenever there is push/comment/etc. on my project. I am also able to see notifications coming in Jenkins whenever any activity happens in my Project on Gitlab.

Now, I want to access the user details at the Jenkins side, who posted a commit/comment on the project. As per gitlab documentation, these are the parameters sent by Gitlab : https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

How can I access them on Jenkins console and do something based on the data received. 
e.g

```
if(commit by X) //need to get X from POST request
   accept
else
   warning
```